# Changing the language of menu items

Tags: javascript, arrays, chinese-locale, multiple-languages

I'm trying to add a new locale and the language change option to a menu I created.

Below you can see the code that I have my progress so far

Essentially, I'd like the menu items for "sports" and "districts" to change to Chinese after the radio button for "中文“ is clicked.  My JavaScript skill is very low so I'm having problems making this happen.  Since it's a short list and I can write Chinese without problem, I thought there may be a simple fix, but so far I haven't made any progress.  Any suggestions on how to go about this is much appreciated.

```html
<body>

  <form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="language" value="english">English<br>
    <input type="radio" name="language" value="chinese">中文<br>
  </form>

</body>

<b>Find your sport</b>
<form>
  <select name="Sports">
    <option value="basketball">Basketball</option>
    <option value="football">Football</option>
    <option value="badminton" selected>Badminton</option>
    <option value="table tennis">Table Tennis</option>
    <option value="swimming">Swimming</option>
    <option value="billiards">Billiards</option>
    <option value="archery">Archery</option>
    <option value="baseball">Baseball</option>
    <option value="bowling">Bowling</option>
    <option value="climbing">Climbing</option>
    <option value="darts">Darts</option>
    <option value="fencing">Fencing</option>
    <option value="golf">Golf</option>
    <option value="squash">Squash</option>
    <option value="tennis">Tennis</option>
  </select>
</form>


<b>Find your district</b>
<form>
  <select name="Districts">
    <option value="xuhui">Xuhui</option>
    <option value="jingan">Jingan</option>
    <option value="huangpu" selected>Huangpu</option>
    <option value="changning">Changning</option>
    <option value="pudong">Pudong</option>
    <option value="putuo">Putuo</option>
    <option value="hongkou" selected>Hongkou</option>
    <option value="yangpu">Yangpu</option>
    <option value="minhang">Minhang</option>
    <option value="songjiang">Songjiang</option>
    <option value="qingpu" selected>Qingpu</option>
    <option value="jiading">Jiading</option>
    <option value="baoshan">Baoshan</option>
    <option value="fengxian">Fengxian</option>
    <option value="jinshan" selected>Jinshan</option>
    <option value="chongming">Chongming</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getVenues();" />
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Neither the code here nor the code at codepen shows any JS code to handle the language switch

Comment: Well I decided to instead try an addEventListener() to just switch the words from English to Chinese when the Chinese button( id= "chinese_button">中文<br>) is pressed since I know both of the languages.  Still working on it

Comment: Is this the complete page?  Because it is missing many tags (`<html>, <head>, <title>`, ...).  Also all your HTML should be "inside" the `<body> </body>` tags.  See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp for basic info.

Comment: Please [edit] your question (do *not* add comments) and provide your code as a [mcve]. You may want to take the [tour] of the site to understand how to ask.

Comment: Another minor note: your "Districts" list of options has multiple `selected` ones which is not nice (may lead to unexpected behaviour)

Comment: Yes I know about the selected comment.  Any thoughts on how to fix the actual problem though?